# how to use wget with several parameters in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have to use wget command to send a request.
My original shell script is below:

> wget --post-data
>   'params=$params&uri=$uri&projectId=$projectId&suiteId=$suiteId&runId=$runId&projectNameValue=$projectNameValue&caseIdStart=$caseIdStart&caseIdEnd=$caseIdEnd&mockFlag=$mockFlag'
>   http://10.139.11.150:9999/SEAutoTest2/testrun/testrail

This wget command transports several parameters to a page.
I use pipeline-syntax to achieve the pipeline code, however it dosen't work.
The parameters cannot achieve from String Parameters.

Here is my jenkins configration screenshot.

[image: Here is my jenkins configration screenshot.]

Here is my pipeline code：

```
node('dev_ci_env_migu') {
properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'VERSION'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'SVN_ADDRESS'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'TEST_ENV'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'USER'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'PASSWD'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'PACKAGE_PATH'), string(description: '', name: 'params'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'projectNameValue'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'uri'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'projectId'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'suiteId'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'runId'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'caseIdStart'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'caseIdEnd'), string(defaultValue: ' ', description: ' ', name: 'mockFlag')]), pipelineTriggers([])])
withEnv(['INTERNAL_PATH=/data/path']) {
    //get code from svn
    stage 'Checkout'
    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: '', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: '$SVN_ADDRESS']], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
    //compile & generate war
    stage 'Build'
    sh '''source /home/migu/.bashrc
cd $WORKSPACE
mvn clean install -DskipTests'''
stage('Automation Test'){
input 'Is test automation preparation job done?'
sh 'wget --post-data 'params=${params}&uri=${uri}&projectId=${projectId}&suiteId=${suiteId}&runId=${runId}&projectNameValue=${projectNameValue}&caseIdStart=${caseIdStart}&caseIdEnd=${caseIdEnd}&mockFlag=${mockFlag}\' http://10.139.11.150:9999/SEAutoTest2/testrun/testrail'
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most script languages you use double-quote (") when you want variable substitution and single-quote (') when you don't want variable substitution.

If you adapt your code to use `"` instead of `'` it should work. Might need special handling of the single quote inside the outer one:

Untested:

```
sh "wget --post-data \"params=${params}&uri=${uri}&projectId=${projectId}&suiteId=${suiteId}&runId==${runId}&projectNameValue=${projectNameValue}&caseIdStart=${caseIdStart}&caseIdEnd=${caseIdEnd}&mockFlag=${mockFlag}\" http://10.139.11.150:9999/SEAutoTest2/testrun/testrail"
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem which troubled me for a long time. I use your suggestion, it finally works.